# Leaving tmux scrollback in terminal (iTerm2)

Tags: ssh, tmux, gnu-screen, tty, iterm

Usually `tmux` will only show as much output as however many rows my terminal currently displays. And then when I detach it, it clears all of its content. I know how to look at scrollback (`ctrl+A`, `[`, `k`, ...), but how can I configure tmux to just print all its output to terminal, as if I wasn't using it at all?

I like `tmux` because I'm awful at remembering to `nohup` certain tasks, and because it makes viewing the output of long-running jobs easier. But I would like to be able to view its scrollback more naturally, by simply *scrolling back* in iTerm2.

Alternatively, if there's a way to do this in `screen`, I can use that too.

Comment: Mark, that question is aptly titled "How do I scroll in tmux." I know how to scroll in tmux. In my question I said I knew how to scroll in tmux. I don't see which of the answers to that question address my problem of retaining tmux buffer in my terminal.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

iTerm2 build 1.0.0.20130302 has an preference which enables it to capture scrollback even when a so-called hard status line is present:

[image: iTerm2 preferences pane]

Works for me, tested with `tmux` v1.8.

Comment: That option checked solved my prominent problem/thought to stick around with tmux. Great. Now I'll stick to tmux one more time.

Comment: Well it worked for the window but it doesn't work for Panes. Is there any option to get this same feature?

Comment: FYI this seems to work with `screen` and `hardstatus on` also, thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I stumbled across an alternative solution on Superuser.com: [Use terminal scrollbar with tmux](https://superuser.com/questions/310251/use-terminal-scrollbar-with-tmux). Add this to your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
# Pretend our terminal doesn't support alternative screens, and thus all text 
# should be placed into the scrollback buffer when it goes off the top of the 
# screen.
#
# https://superuser.com/questions/310251/use-terminal-scrollbar-with-tmux
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ',xterm*:smcup@:rmcup@'
```

Works for me with `gnome-terminal` v3.4.1.1 and `tmux` v1.9

Comment: This works great for me too. I also needed to add `set-window-option -g mouse-mode off` to my `.tmux.conf`.

Comment: @Ben You probably mean `mode-mouse`, not `mouse-mode`. Your suggestion results in `unknown option: mouse-mode` on my system.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your `~/.tmux.conf` and you will be able to enter copy mode just by scrolling:

```
setw -g mode-mouse on
```

You may also want to enable other mouse features:

```
set -g mouse-resize-pane on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
```

See this excellent write-up of these features: http://tangledhelix.com/blog/2012/07/16/tmux-and-mouse-mode/

Comment: Just FYI, these options have been bundled and renamed to `set -g mouse on`.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, just putting `set-option -g status off` in `.tmux.conf` allows to leave the scrollback in the terminal. But you lose the status bar.